# SQL Join Problem... what is it called?

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables that are joined. I've included the 'output' of the joined tables. I'm wondering what is this join problem called? There are duplicating rows.

> **Table 1**                **Table
>   2**   
>   **ID      Name        ID  Name**
>
>   1     Joey            4   Mary
>   2     Shawn        5 Xavier
>   3     Mark            6   Gary

The join output is:

> **ID      Name        ID Name**
>   4     Mary        1   Joey
>   4     Mary        2   Shawn
>   4     Mary        3   Mark
>   5     Xavier    1   Joey
>   5     Xavier    2   Shawn
>   5     Xavier    3   Mark
>   6     Gary        1   Joey
>   6     Gary        2   Shawn
>   6     Gary        3   Mark

Comment: Haha, no it's not homework I'm just trying to communicate a problem to my coworker and I want to be specific about what the issue is. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If memory serves, that's called a Cartesian Product.

Comment: It's also called a cross-join.

Comment: but doesn't "Cartesian Product" sound more computerish?

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is that you want to use [`UNION`](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlunion.php), not [`JOIN`](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php).

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 UNION SELECT * FROM Table2;
```

Should give you:

```
ID  Name
1   Joey
2   Shawn
3   Mark
4   Mary
5   Xavier
6   Gary
```

Is this what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

It is [CROSS JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_join#Cross_join).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your output, your query is something like

```
SELECT * FROM Table2, Table1
```

This is called a CROSS JOIN and this is the normal behavior that for each row in table2, the values from table1 will be appended.

What you seem to want is a UNION

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM Table2
```